# Make new array partially from another array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I am very new to Swift, so excuse me if this is a dumb question.

I have a JSON `X` array of objects, which I load into my app and pass around views (I have a defined struct for it). Now in another view I have a new struct, which looks like this:

```swift
struct Pin: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    let id = UUID()
}
```

and later make an array like so:

```swift
@State private var pins: [Pin] = []
```

How can I make this array to contain `Pin` objects, but made from my existing `X` array. What I mean that each new `Pin` inside `pins` array would have the values of `Pin(name: X.name[0]` and so on for each element in my `X` array.

So my final `pins` array should look something like:

```
[Pin(name: x.name[0]...), Pin(name: x.name[1]...), Pin(name: x.name[2]...)...]
```

Comment: What exactly is `X` array? And what about the `image` in the new array?

Comment: @pawello2222 the `X` array is an array of objects, each with a `name`, `description` and couple other fields I don't need for this particular view. You can ignore the image, I was gonna have it but ultimately decided not to, will remove it from the code sample :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) to convert one array to another:

```
pins = x.map { Pin(name: $0.name) }
```

or, slower but shows another way of using `map`:

```
pins = x.map(\.name).map(Pin.init)
```

Comment: AH amazing, that did exactly what I needed it to do! I am a JavaScript dev and use maps every single day, but for some reason it did not occur to me that they can also be used in Swift... Anyway, thank you so much!